# WPF Credits effect problem: StoryBoard to animate a StackPanel that extends the height of the window

Tags: wpf, storyboard, stackpanel, credits

This is my first WPF project. I'm trying to get a rolling credits effect with a bunch of banner-shaped PNG's stacked on top of each other vertically.

My current approach is to have a bunch of images in a StackPanel. Each image is approx 1024x150, and there is about 30 images.  They stack vertically.

I start the StackPanel at 0,200, so most of it is off screen. I then have a StoryBoard (created in Blend) that translates it up the Y axis, all the way off-screen. The animation starts, but **the problem is the part of the StackPanel that was originally off-screen never paints and stays cut off.** Only the initially visible area of the StackPanel animates.

It feels like the StackPanel needs to be repainted. Is this approach ever going to work or do I need to do something totally different?

XAML, omitting Window and Window.Triggers:

```
<Window.Resources>
    <Storyboard x:Key="sb_HR">
        <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames 
                    BeginTime="00:00:00" 
                    Storyboard.TargetName="StackPanel1"
                    Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.RenderTransform).(TransformGroup.Children)[3].(TranslateTransform.Y)">
            <SplineDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="00:00:30" Value="-1950"/>
        </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
    </Storyboard>
</Window.Resources>


<Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot">
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="1024" />
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>        
    <StackPanel   Name="StackPanel1" Margin="0,0,0,0" RenderTransformOrigin="0.5,0.5">
        <StackPanel.RenderTransform>
            <TransformGroup>
                <ScaleTransform ScaleX="1" ScaleY="1"/>
                <SkewTransform AngleX="0" AngleY="0"/>
                <RotateTransform Angle="0"/>
                <TranslateTransform X="0" Y="0"/>
            </TransformGroup>
        </StackPanel.RenderTransform>
        <Image Margin="0,50,0,0" Source="title.png"  x:Name="title" Height="150" VerticalAlignment="Top" Stretch="Uniform"></Image>
        <Image Margin="0,50,0,0" Source="1.png" x:Name="V1_L1" Height="150" VerticalAlignment="Top" Stretch="Uniform" ></Image>
        <Image Margin="0,50,0,0" Source="2.png" x:Name="V1_L2" Height="150" VerticalAlignment="Top" Stretch="Uniform" ></Image>
        <Image Margin="0,50,0,0" Source="3.png" x:Name="V1_L3" Height="150" VerticalAlignment="Top" Stretch="Uniform" ></Image>
        <Image Margin="0,50,0,0" Source="4.png" x:Name="V1_L4" Height="150" VerticalAlignment="Top" Stretch="Uniform" ></Image>
        <Image Margin="0,50,0,0" Source="5.png" x:Name="V1_L5" Height="150" VerticalAlignment="Top" Stretch="Uniform" ></Image>
        <Image Margin="0,50,0,0" Source="6.png" x:Name="V1_L6" Height="150" VerticalAlignment="Top" Stretch="Uniform" ></Image>
        <Image Margin="0,50,0,0" Source="7.png" x:Name="V1_L7" Height="150" VerticalAlignment="Top" Stretch="Uniform" ></Image>
        <Image Margin="0,50,0,0" Source="8.png" x:Name="V1_L8" Height="150" VerticalAlignment="Top" Stretch="Uniform" ></Image>
    </StackPanel>
</Grid>
```

**EDIT:** I've found ClipToBounds and tried setting it to false, but it is already false. Someone on MSDN has the same problem as me, at http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/wpf/thread/5764645e-cb4f-4137-a525-4e8698ee43b6 - I don't think there's a solution yet.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I see two things that you could try out:

1. Use a ScrollViewer with disabled scrollbars around the StackPanel. Sadly, you cannot animate the scroll offset directly, so you would need to create something like a timer in code behind and call ScrollToVerticalOffset() periodically.
2. Try putting the StackPanel on a Canvas and animate Canvas.Top (set on the StackPanel) instead of the RenderTransforms.

I will supply a code sample if you need one.

Andrej

Answer (score 2):

I agree with Andrej, just make a new List Box type that has the scrollbars disabled.

You can animate the scroll offset, I've got it happening in a Custom Control I'm writing right now.  This is in a function in the class for the List Box:

---

```
Duration animationDuration = new Duration(new TimeSpan(0, 0, 0, 0, _scrollSpeed));
DoubleAnimation animateHscroll = new DoubleAnimation(thisScrollViewer.HorizontalOffset, TargetHorizontalOffset, animationDuration);

thisScrollViewer.BeginAnimation(HorizontalScrollOffsetProperty, animateHscroll);
```

---